# Issue with the proxy settings when installing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I have the same issue with Eclipse (Neon 4.6 eclipse installer by Oomph 32 bit) as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841199/is-there-any-way-of-configuring-eclipse-ide-proxy-settings-via-an-autoproxy-conf) and as explained there I have downloaded the automatic configuration script (the script is set up through the Group Policy so I can’t change my LAN settings) that my browser is using. I used the host and port in the return statement and did as explained below

- Select the "HTTP" line and click the edit button
- Add the IP address and port number above to the http line:

  [image]

Does anyone know what else I can try because I am still getting a network problem message?
Your help will be appreciated

Proxy Network problem message:
[image: Proxy Network problem message]

Comment: Edited to inline images, fix bullets points, shorten link

Comment: Thanks greg-449 for formating the message!

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the active provider to Manual and retried again, then it worked.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. I ended up installing the .zip file instead.

Comment: Under Proxy entries, select HTTP or HTTPS and click edit button. In the dialog, add host, port, username, password. It will work. HTTPS worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an old version and it's worked well.

this is the link for the old version: 
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen/2

Answer (score 0):

You can download a zip file of the Eclipse package you want and explode it in your filesystem where you want it,
Here is link for Eclipse package for windows:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-06/R/eclipse-java-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=17

Or select another package here:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had similar issues to this that related to my office network and their use of a security tool called Netskope which needed its root-certificate into the jvm that would be used by the Eclipse installer. I elaborated on my workaround steps in this other thread:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171147/1302220

Answer (score 0):

Dont add SOCK just type ip and port for http and https and select manual.
This worked for me as I am using proxy for connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).