# Oomph installer error: The catalog could not be loaded

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I'm trying to install a newer version of Eclipse.  The Oomph Eclipse installer keeps giving me the following error:

[image]

I'm definitely connected to the network - and I've done everything I can think of with Configure Network Proxy Settings.  I still get the error every time.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have the Eclipse 2021-03 Installer and not an outdated one. It might also be an outage at Eclipse or in between Eclipse and you. See: https://www.eclipsestatus.io/

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768872/issue-with-the-proxy-settings-when-installing-eclipse. It has some answers (none that work for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on linux mint, so I clicked on change the proxy settings and only changed to manual and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

I experienced something similar today. For me, it related to my company's internet making use of a security tool called Netskope that intercepts https traffic (yep, companies are sniffing our private traffic too now ;)).

I've experienced similar network issues with other tools at work (like python pip installer), and our IT dept advised that we need to install a Netskope root certificate into any tool we use that doesn't make use of the operating system's security store (and they use their own).

So, to get a feel for how this issue impacted me in relation to this "eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe" installer file, I learnt that I could run the installer with an extra argument, to specify my own jvm:

```
eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\"
```

This got me the following error:

[image: JVM not suitable error]

...and that was the clue I needed to realise that this Eclipse installer .exe had JDK 11 built into it.

So, given that, I felt that I should try download my own JDK 11 and add this 'netskope.pem' root certificate into that, so I'll share my steps in doing so:

I grabbed jdk-11 from here:

- http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11

I extracted the “openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip” file onto my local drive

- E.g. to “C:\Users\GurceI\Downloads\jdk-11\”

Added ‘nscacert.pem’ to jdk-11’s keystore from the command-line, with:

```
cd c:\Users\GurceI\Downloads\jdk-11\

bin\keytool.exe -import -keystore lib\security\cacerts -file c:\ProgramData\netskope\stagent\download\nscacert.pem
```

(default keystore password = “changeit”)

I then ran the eclipse-installer with an extra argument to point it to my jdk-11 (rather than its internal one):

```
eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe -vm "C:\Users\GurceI\Downloads\jdk-11\"
```

...and then, finally, the installer worked, no more network issues :)

[image]

Comment: this is awsome man, I've tried a lot of things to go through the corporate proxy but never crossed my mind that its the certificate that's causing the issue. Eclipse should use an http download if https fails or atleast show some error to give us a clue. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Worked for me, behind a company proxy that breaks SSL. Eclipse should definitely give a more specific error.

Comment: Great answer amigo.  This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error with "The catalog could not be loaded.  Please ensure that you have network access... on my Windows 10 laptop.

I know the installer works since I was able to install Eclipse on another system.  I went to eclipse.org, then to More, Eclipse IDE Download, then choose
"Get Eclipse", then click on Download Packages. Choose your OS.  In my case, I chose Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Windows x86_64.  This will start downloading the eclipse install .zip file.

Once unzipped, I was able to install by launching the .exe.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is eclipse installer is using its own jdk for installation which is present under `eclipse-inst.ini` . The installation details can be found after `-vm` line.

If your organisation mandated to use their own root certificate then you have to first add root certificate's entry into your JDK & then modify `eclipse-inst.ini` to point to your installed JDK.

So to fix this issue, you can either refer @Gurce's great answer or you can do following: :

1. Download certificate & add root entry to following (Mac command) :

`sudo keytool -importcert -file "/Users/<User Account Folder Name>/Documents/cert.pem" -alias anyalias -keystore "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JAVA Version Folder Name>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit`

2. Once added you can verify if entries gets added or not by using following command:

`keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts`

3. After this, download eclipse installer & find `eclipse-inst.ini` file.
4. Open that file in text editor mode & find line which is present after `-vm`
5. Remove that jdk version & use your own installed jdk which has your  organisation's root cert. So modified ini file will look like , (other file details omitted) :

> ```
>  ...
>      -vm
>      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk
>      -vmargs
>  ..
> ```

If its not required to add root certificate into JDKs `cacerts`, then you can directly follow point 3 ,  use your own installed JDK in `ini` file & see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

change "native" to "manual" and then you configurate your http and https proxy parameters, it works to me! (Windows)

Comment: can you please share how you configured http and https proxy parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Here I treid everything but at the end this error can be sorted by

1. uninstall the java JRE
2. Uninstall the java JDK

Then again install the eclipse
After that you can again install  java JDK and JRE