# Nothing happening after double clicking Eclipse Installer executable (eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe) on windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse

Nothing happening after double clicking Eclipse Installer executable (eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe) on windows 10

Comment: The instructions for installing Eclipse on Windows using the installer are here:  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But nothing is happening after clicking on Eclipse Installer executable

Comment: If you intend to use an existing Java installation with Eclipse, check the Eclipse release notes to make sure that your version of Java is supported.   From Eclipse 4.19 a compatible JRE is included in the installer.  (See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)

Comment: If nothing happens, when you click the installer, try running it from the command shell.  Also check that you have a complete download.

Comment: ...and that you have execution permission on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with following steps :-

- Open powershell as admin right and type below command

PS C:\Users\user123\Downloads> .\eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe -clean -clearPersistedState

- It opened installer
- Setup proxy server if you have any with this link
  [Issue with the proxy settings when installing Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768872/issue-with-the-proxy-settings-when-installing-eclipse)
- Installer automatically set JVM if already installed
- Select Installation folder for current user
- And start the installation