# Portable Eclipse : impossible to add software

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, p2, portable-applications

I installed Eclipse on my office pc, using this procedure (64 bit): https://portableapps.com/node/53284
But when i want to create a new project, it does not propose me the usual "Java project" with minimal files written.
I don't have the Java Perspective so I'm trying to install the dev tools but when I want check a software site, eclipse keeps telling me it doesn't find it.

What i have done so far:

-Putted Active Provider on "Direct" in network connections

-The Eclipse Internal Web Browser works just fine (including the repositories urls and able to download files)

-I've tryed with an "/" at the end of the urls (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13/ and http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/mars/)

-I've tryed to download http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13/compositeContent.jar and opened it manually. Didn't worked.

-I've added "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" after "-vmargs" in my eclipse.ini then restarted. Same.

It keeps searching for http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13/content.xml and http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/mars/content.xml which do not exist. (Unknown Host... org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException)

But I don't know how to change that into compositeContent since Eclipse starts to look for compositeContent.[xml/jar]/content.xml instead.

Could you help me?

[About my Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPEN.png)

Comment: An Eclipse update site must have one of, but not all of `compositeContent.xml`, `compositeContent.xml`, `content.jar` and `content.xml`. So searching for one of these although it does not exist is as should be (since it is not known in advance which one exists). Downloading one of these files makes no sense (it is only a part of the update site). What did you want to achieve with it? What do you exactly have (see _Help > About..._)? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I know that, but since http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/mars/compositeContent.xml exists for instance, it should see it. But Eclispe pass it and tells me content.xml does not exist, which is true... I've tryed to download the jar file to see if I could add the repository from my disk instead of looking on the web. I have Eclipse Version: 2019-09 (4.13)  Build id: I20190916-1045 . I am on the vpn of my company but since the integrated browser in Eclispe works, I don't think there is a particular proxy.

Comment: `.../mpc/mars/...` means [Eclipse Marketpace Client (MPC)](https://www.eclipse.org/mpc/) of the [Mars release](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/mars). Instead, use the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/) or [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) (you are one release behind, the current release is 2019-12). Since the Java perspective is missing, which Eclipse IDE package do you have?

Comment: Same error: Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/content.xml
Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/content.xml
download.eclipse.org

Where do I see the package I have?

Comment: In the about dialog the first line says which IDE package do you have. What are your settings in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections_?

Comment: Version: 2019-09 (4.13)
Build id: I20190916-1045

My network is on "Direct"

Comment: Please show the about dialog. _Direct_ means not using a proxy which fails if the proxy is the only way. If _Native_ does not work, you have to configure it _Manual_.

Comment: I've added the About menu. In fact, Native does not work and asks for http proxy authentification. I've asked in my office and there is indeed a proxy but I don't think I have the ids to configure it. Portable Firefox works fine but the network options are on "Use the system proxy parameters".

Comment: Alright, it works! I'll edit my original post with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works! There was indeed a proxy on my company network, with an autoconfig file.

I've putted my network options on "Manual" and followed the instructions there : [Is there any way of configuring Eclipse IDE proxy settings via an autoproxy configuration script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841199/is-there-any-way-of-configuring-eclipse-ide-proxy-settings-via-an-autoproxy-conf)

Now it works perfectly! Thanks to howlger for helping me getting in the right direction \o/

Comment: Great that it works now. You have the Eclipse Platform/Runtime, not an Eclipse IDE package. [Eclipse IDE packages can be downloaded as ZIP (or `.dmg` for macOS) here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).